# How can I produce the history graph of a Git repository in LaTeX?

Tags: graphs, git, gitdags

Is there a relatively simple way to produce the history graph of a git repository in LaTeX? I'm looking for something nicer-looking than the verbatim output of

```
git log --graph --oneline
```

Comment: Not a graphical solution but is something like [latex-git-log](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-git-log) sufficient?

Comment: It I am not mistaken, latex-git-log just tabulates the history. Not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 42):

I have begun an attempt at an answer here. It would involve piping the output of `$ git log --graph --oneline` to a text file and having LaTeX parse that for information. We'd need to determine the nest level of the asterisk (branch level), which is what I'm not sure how to accomplish.

Here is a MWE using a section of the tree from one of my projects:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% gitgraph.txt contains raw output of: $ git log --graph --oneline
\begin{filecontents}{gitgraph.txt}
* d764b48 added plaintext version in markdown
* 54ba4b2 release 2014-01-25
*   c589395 Merge branch 'master'
|\
| * 9f9c652 Remove holdover from kjh gh-pages branch
* | b3bd158 exclude font files
|/
* 63268c1 micro-typography
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\commit[2]{\node[commit] (#1) {}; \node[clabel] at (#1) {\texttt{#1}: #2};}
\newcommand\ghost[1]{\coordinate (#1);}
\newcommand\connect[2]{\path (#1) to[out=90,in=-90] (#2);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{commit}=[draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt]
\tikzstyle{clabel}=[right,outer sep=1em]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[draw]
\matrix [column sep={1em,between origins},row sep=\lineskip]
{
\commit{d764b48}{added plaintext version in markdown} & \\
\commit{54ba4b2}{release 2014-01-25} & \\
\commit{c589395}{Merge branch `master'} & \\
 & \commit{9f9c652}{Remove holdover from kjh gh-pages branch} \\
\commit{b3bd158}{exclude font files} & \ghost{branch1} \\
\commit{63268c1}{micro-typography} & \\
};
\connect{63268c1}{b3bd158};
\connect{63268c1}{branch1};
\connect{branch1}{9f9c652};
\connect{b3bd158}{c589395};
\connect{9f9c652}{c589395};
\connect{c589395}{54ba4b2};
\connect{54ba4b2}{d764b48};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the output:
[image: example output]

This could be easily stylized in whatever way you wish. Of course the main issue is going to be finding a solution to parse the commit tree. Maybe `pgfplotstable` could be used?

Comment: This looks very nice! As you pointed out, the trick is going to be parsing the git output.

Comment: Man, this looks sweet. It just lacks automation. Have you considered writing a package to generate the `tikz` code based on the git log? I sure would be interested in such a package, and I'm sure others would too.

Comment: @Jubobs, I've looked into this and I think this is the best route. One could write a hook to write this tree (`$ git log --graph --oneline --all`) or a pre-parsed version of it into a file to be read/processed by TeX/TikZ. This is  the approach used by the [`gitinfo`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gitinfo) package.

Comment: For a linear history (i.e., without branches and merges), `git log --format="\commit{%h}{%s} & \\"` can be used at least to write the matrix part of the code.  More info in the [`git-log` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Answer (score 35):

As I'm working on a Git tutorial that includes several history graphs, I have, for convenience, written a little package (built on top of TikZ v3.0) called `gitdags`.

Automatic generation of history graphs of (possibly large) repositories is *not* the purpose of [`gitdags`](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags). Rather, the package is meant to allow you to effortlessly draw nice graphs for demonstrating the effects of Git commands such as `checkout`, `reset`, `merge`, `rebase`, etc.

The package itself is little more than a bunch of TikZ styles and a couple of macros but, because some Stack-Overflow users have expressed an interest in it, I've made the code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Jubobs/), and I have plans to submit the package to CTAN in the near future...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gitdags}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Commit DAG
      \gitDAG[grow right sep = 2em]{
        A -- B -- { 
          C,
          D -- E,
        }
      };
      % Tag reference
      \gittag
        [v0p1]       % node name
        {v0.1}       % node text
        {above=of A} % node placement
        {A}          % target
      % Remote branch
      \gitremotebranch
        [origmaster]    % node name
        {origin/master} % node text
        {above=of C}    % node placement
        {C}             % target
      % Branch
      \gitbranch
        {master}     % node name and text 
        {above=of E} % node placement
        {E}          % target
      % HEAD reference
      \gitHEAD
        {above=of master} % node placement
        {master}          % target
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{Before\ldots}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \gitDAG[grow right sep = 2em]{
        A -- B -- { 
          C -- D' -- E',
          {[nodes=unreachable] D -- E },
        }
      };
      % Tag reference
      \gittag
        [v0p1]       % node name
        {v0.1}       % node text
        {above=of A} % node placement
        {A}          % target
      % Remote branch
      \gitremotebranch
        [origmaster]    % node name
        {origin/master} % node text
        {above=of C}    % node placement
        {C}             % target
      % Branch
      \gitbranch
        {master}      % node name and text 
        {above=of E'} % node placement
        {E'}          % target
      % HEAD reference
      \gitHEAD
        {above=of master} % node placement
        {master}          % target
      \SAandWT
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption{\ldots{} and after \texttt{git rebase origin/master}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Demonstrating a typical \texttt{rebase}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! You've also reminded me that I need to revisit my own answer... :p :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes. I've been thinking about it (automatic generation) too. I've got a few ideas. Perhaps you should start a project on GitHub on which we could both hack...

Comment: I had been using Brent's code from `gitinfo` to create some hooks that would parse the tree output, but I've not had much time to look at it since he deprecated `gitinfo` and moved to `gitinfo2`. All my stuff is in a very early stage, but I'll get it to a post-able state over the weekend and create a repo. I'll ping you in chat when it's live. :-)

Comment: @Jubobs As you pointed out, GitDAGS does something other than what I am looking for. Nevertheless, this is really cool!

Comment: @xvtk Yes, I know my answer is slightly off-topic here, but I thought I'd mention it `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs that is wonderful. I just installed LaTeX for this (after tens of years avoiding even checking what LaTeX is `;)`).
I'm trying to experiment with the syntax (I'm indeed a newbie with it) but I cannot: `1 - ` represent a **git merge**  (understood how to add tree branches, but not how to merge them again to one element/commit) `2 - ` how to invert the direction of the connecting-arrows defined with `--` and how to add more that one to one element/commit. Where could I find more examples?

Comment: @Kamafeather [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thanks for your interest. I have yet to produce a decent documentation for the package; please be patient. I've already heavily edited this answer, so I'd rather leave it as it is. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags/issues/3). If the code there doesn't help you, why not ask a separate question on TeX.SX, perhaps with a sketch of the type of graph you want to produce? I'd be happy to answer it, if I can.

Comment: for reference, I created a tag for `gitdags`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gitdags

Answer (score 13):

Using [the ideas from Paul Gessler's answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156501) I extended 
[the parsing code from Michael Hauspie that I found on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/hauspie/2397222) so that it produces the following output:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{commit}=[draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{branch}=[draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3,fill=white,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=5pt]
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (ef1eae1) at (0.0,0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_ef1eae1) at (ef1eae1.east) {\verb!ef1eae1: Updates my_file.txt for new feature!};
\node[commit, Dandelion, fill=Dandelion] (4f669eb) at (0.5,-0.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_4f669eb) at (4f669eb.east) {\verb!4f669eb: Added README file with basic documentation!};
\node[commit, Dandelion, fill=Dandelion] (9216cb2) at (0.5,-1.0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_9216cb2) at (9216cb2.east) {\verb!9216cb2: Added a start message!};
\node[commit, Red, fill=Red] (77c49c1) at (1.0,-1.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_77c49c1) at (77c49c1.east) {\verb!77c49c1: New script added.!};
\node[commit, Dandelion, fill=Dandelion] (167af36) at (0.5,-2.0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_167af36) at (167af36.east) {\verb!167af36: Added date/time to the final message in the script!};
\path[Dandelion] (167af36) to[out=90,in=-90] (9216cb2);
\path[Dandelion] (167af36) to[out=90,in=-90] (77c49c1);
\node[commit, Dandelion, fill=Dandelion] (a2a2593) at (0.5,-2.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_a2a2593) at (a2a2593.east) {\verb!a2a2593: Merge branch 'Feature1'!};
\path[Dandelion] (a2a2593) to[out=90,in=-90] (167af36);
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (6ea97fa) at (0.0,-3.0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_6ea97fa) at (6ea97fa.east) {\verb!6ea97fa: Added a line to the Feature1 branch!};
\path[ForestGreen] (6ea97fa) to[out=90,in=-90] (ef1eae1);
\path[ForestGreen] (6ea97fa) to[out=90,in=-90] (4f669eb);
\path[ForestGreen] (6ea97fa) to[out=90,in=-90] (a2a2593);
\node[commit, Dandelion, fill=Dandelion] (9f51c0d) at (0.5,-3.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_9f51c0d) at (9f51c0d.east) {\verb!9f51c0d: Added a 'finished' message at the end of the script!};
\path[Dandelion] (9f51c0d) to[out=90,in=-90] (a2a2593);
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (2e10426) at (0.0,-4.0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_2e10426) at (2e10426.east) {\verb!2e10426: Added a line of text to my_file.txt.!};
\path[ForestGreen] (2e10426) to[out=90,in=-90] (6ea97fa);
\path[ForestGreen] (2e10426) to[out=90,in=-90] (9f51c0d);
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (91f1fef) at (0.0,-4.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_91f1fef) at (91f1fef.east) {\verb!91f1fef: Converted another_file.txt to a Bash script.!};
\path[ForestGreen] (91f1fef) to[out=90,in=-90] (2e10426);
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (1ddccf6) at (0.0,-5.0) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_1ddccf6) at (1ddccf6.east) {\verb!1ddccf6: Added a new file and added several lines to my_files.txt.!};
\path[ForestGreen] (1ddccf6) to[out=90,in=-90] (91f1fef);
\node[commit, ForestGreen, fill=ForestGreen] (2f06323) at (0.0,-5.5) {};
\node[right,xshift=10] (label_2f06323) at (2f06323.east) {\verb!2f06323: First commit. Added an important file.!};
\path[ForestGreen] (2f06323) to[out=90,in=-90] (1ddccf6);
\node[branch,right,xshift=10] (Feature1) at (label_4f669eb.east) {\lstinline{Feature1}};
\node[branch,right,xshift=10] (Feature2) at (label_77c49c1.east) {\lstinline{Feature2}};
\node[branch,right,xshift=10] (SubFeature) at (label_ef1eae1.east) {\lstinline{SubFeature}};
\node[branch,right,xshift=10] (master) at (label_9216cb2.east) {\lstinline{master}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It's not perfect, but seems to work for small repositories. The code can be found [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/lckarssen/f3a8e8682fed906068c1).