# Draw graphs (DAGs) in Latex

Tags: graphs

I am searching for a latex package which allows to draw something like the DAGs in [this page](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/).

Does anyone know how to draw them?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Check tikz package, see page 209 http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf. For a lot of tikz examples check also http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/, in particular http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/

Comment: [How can I produce the history graph of a Git repository in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198345) is perhaps of interest.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Generally "do it for me" kind of questions are not welcome in this site. But this is your first day on the site. So here we go.</sub>

Here is a sample with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm]
    \node[ellipse,draw] at (0,0) {Blob};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[ellipse,draw] (a) at (0,0) {Blob};
      \node[ellipse,draw,above = 2cm of a] (b) {Tree};
      \draw[-latex] (b) to[out=20,in=-20,looseness=4]
                        node [right,font=\tiny,align=left] {subdir\\+filename} (b);
      \node[ellipse,draw,above = 2cm of b,align=center] (c) {commit\\-message};
      \draw[-latex] (c) to[out=20,in=-20,looseness=4]
                        node [right,font=\tiny,align=left] {parents} (c);
      \draw[-latex] (c) -- (b);
      \draw[-latex] (b) -- node[right, align=left]{+ File name \\ + node} (a);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll use it as pattern for future graphs!

Comment: @Lorlo Glad it helped. Remeber that you can accept the useful answers to say thanks. For details see: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)